# Spawning with TcpStream leads to 10061 ConnectionRefused

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to make a simple host which can handle multiple streams (similar to the example given in https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial):

```rust
use std::{error::Error, time::Duration};
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    time::sleep,
};

type GenericResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    const ADDRESS: &str = "127.0.0.1:8080";
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(ADDRESS).await.unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(async { host(listener) });
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(ADDRESS).await.unwrap();
    stream.write_all(b"testing").await.unwrap();
}
async fn host(listener: TcpListener) -> GenericResult<()> {
    loop {
        let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        println!("new connection");
        tokio::spawn(async { process(stream).await.unwrap() });
    }
    async fn process(mut stream: TcpStream) -> GenericResult<()> {
        // Reads from stream
        let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(128);
        let mut position = 0;
        loop {
            // Read from stream into buffer
            let n = stream.read(&mut buffer[position..]).await?;
            // Advance position
            position += n;
            // Print buffer
            println!("buffer: {:?}", buffer);
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    }
}
```

But when running this I encounter:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 10061, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." }', src\main.rs:12:56
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Any help would be really appreciated here.

Specifically why my implementation here differs (in functionality) from a working implementation in https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b944a8c4703d438d48ef5e556f1fc08

`cargo --version --verbose`:

```
cargo 1.60.0 (d1fd9fe2c 2022-03-01)
release: 1.60.0
commit-hash: d1fd9fe2c40a1a56af9132b5c92ab963ac7ae422
commit-date: 2022-03-01
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
libgit2: 1.3.0 (sys:0.13.23 vendored)
libcurl: 7.80.0-DEV (sys:0.4.51+curl-7.80.0 vendored ssl:Schannel)
os: Windows 10.0.22000 (Windows 10 Pro) [64-bit]
```

With `tokio = {version="1.18.0",features=["full"]}`

Comment: Do you have a TCP server running on port 8080?

Comment: @isaactfa I don't think so.

Comment: That'll probably do it. Can't say for sure how Windows handles this, but I reckon that's what's happening. You're trying to listen on a closed port.

Comment: Seems likely you don't have the server running. You can always try to connect to some known server and see if the error remains.

Comment: @isaactfa How does my application here differ (in practical functionality) from this example (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b944a8c4703d438d48ef5e556f1fc08)?

Comment: @isaactfa This code works fine for me, I don't what else to say here.

Comment: The difference is that in your code you're spawning the task that listens before you've connected the stream. Try moving the line with the `let mut stream = ...` declaration one line up, above the spawning of the task.

Comment: @isaactfa Could you give an example of what you mean? A fix?

Comment: Like I say, just move the definition of the stream before you start to listen on it. I posted it as an answer so you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the stream *before* you start listening on it.

```
use std::{error::Error, time::Duration};
use tokio::{
    io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt},
    net::{TcpListener, TcpStream},
    time::sleep,
};

type GenericResult<T> = Result<T, Box<dyn Error>>;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    const ADDRESS: &str = "127.0.0.1:8080";
    let listener = TcpListener::bind(ADDRESS).await.unwrap();
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(ADDRESS).await.unwrap();
    tokio::spawn(async { host(listener) });
    stream.write_all(b"testing").await.unwrap();
}
async fn host(listener: TcpListener) -> GenericResult<()> {
    loop {
        let (stream, _) = listener.accept().await?;
        println!("new connection");
        tokio::spawn(async { process(stream).await.unwrap() });
    }
    async fn process(mut stream: TcpStream) -> GenericResult<()> {
        // Reads from stream
        let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(128);
        let mut position = 0;
        loop {
            // Read from stream into buffer
            let n = stream.read(&mut buffer[position..]).await?;
            // Advance position
            position += n;
            // Print buffer
            println!("buffer: {:?}", buffer);
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you in this example allow new streams to connect to the listener at runtime? (E.g. testing an example where we create a 'server' listener then periodically connect new 'client' streams)

Comment: Create a new listener for every stream. But that strikes me as a different question. Why don't you mark this as done, try to add more streams and ask another question if you're having trouble?